# Ruby on Rails Creating a new page for each element

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a webpage for movies and in the database there are 100 movies. I would like to route each movie to their own page (localhost:3000/movie/1) with their own description (in the database) on RoR. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `movies_controller.

More info here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Thanks. Been a while since I last used it. Now I remember.